# Orderby descending mongdb query - Javascript, mongodb and Kinvey

Tags: javascript, mongodb, kinvey

How can I order my query using javascript and mongodb on kinvey platform?
This is my query

```
var findData = modules.collectionAccess.collection('myCollection').find({"idColetor": {"$eq": 659238569}}, limit=2);
```

I've tried

> .sort({"tsmilliseconds":-1});

and

> $orderby: { tsmilliseconds : -1 }

but anyone is working.

Tks

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: "TypeError: Object [object Promise] has no method 'sort'" @inspired

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24799342/804928) helps you

Comment: I got the same error @inspired. Tk u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your sort parameter in object and pass it as second parameter in find method. So your method should look like this:

```
modules.collectionAccess.collection('myCollection').find({"idColetor": {"$eq": 659238569}}, {"limit":2,"sort":{"tsmilliseconds":-1}, function(err, results){});
```

Here your can find documentation: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/reference/business-logic/reference.html#collection-access-module